# Including jQuery with Angular breaks bootstrap select input

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I include jQuery before angular.js my bootstrap select formatting breaks. If it is included after all Angular includes, all is well. I have shuffled the order around every way I can think. Bootstrap.js before angular etc. Maybe hard to explain, please see screenshots.

[image: Proper functionality]
[image: Select formatting breaks]

Here is teh actual select. Nothing fancy here. Some CSS changes to remove some of bootstraps styles. Nothing hacky.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error' : searchForm.cabinClass.$invalid && !searchForm.cabinClass.$pristine}">
          <select class="form-control" name="cabinClass" data-ng-model="search.searchparams.journeys[0].cabinclass" required=""/>
                <option value="Economy" selected>Economy</option>
                <option value="Premiumeconomy">Premium Economoy</option>
                <option value="Business">Business Class</option>
                <option value="First">First Class</option>
            </select>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Here is the JS include section

```
<script src="content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Vendor Libs: jQuery only used for Bootstrap functionality -->
<script src="scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-messages.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-payments.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-smooth-scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- UI Libs -->
<script src="content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="content/js/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- App libs -->
<script src="build/js/app.js"></script>
```

Pretty clueless as to why including jQuery before angular.js would cause this.

There are no console errors and everything else, like datepickers, function normally.

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you really need all of jQuery? If you don't include it at all (or include it after Angular) Angular will use jqlite which is a tiny version of jQuery, and it does most things pretty well.

Comment: Hey mate, so far I was fine without it and I am aware that jQlite is used. I can probably live without it, although I am hoping to write something similar to the bootstrap affix plugin. jQuery would make this easier. It's as much a curiosity thing as it is a necessity at this point. Thanks for your interest!